# writeToFile not properly saving data

Tags: objective-c, file, metadata, nsdata

I have data from a url (.m4a) and I am trying to save the file so I can edit it's metadata (change background image). The code below doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why. It is saving a file, but the file is empty.

```
_previewData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a281.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/119/Music/v4/f1/7b/d6/f17bd6e3-55c0-b7e0-9863-bc522900e950/mzaf_5153970109972844579.aac.m4a"]];
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"file.mp4"]];
                NSFileManager *filemanager;
                filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                [_previewData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
                if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
                    // Runs
                    NSLog(@"It worked");
                }
                NSLog(@"%@",path);

ANMovie* file = [[ANMovie alloc] initWithFile:path]; // or .mp4
                NSData* jpegCover = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(artworkImage, 1.0);
                _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegCover];
                ANMetadata* metadata = [[ANMetadata alloc] init];
                metadata.albumCover = [[ANMetadataImage alloc] initWithImageData:jpegCover type:ANMetadataImageTypeJPG];
                [file setMovieMetadata:metadata];
                [file close];

                    _previewData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
                NSDictionary *imageItem=@{@"public.mpeg-4-audio":self.previewData};
                NSDictionary *textItem=@{@"public.plain-text":self.linkData};

                pasteboard.items=@[imageItem,textItem];
```

Comment: At what point is the posted code causing an issue? Did you look at `_previewData`? Does it have the correct amount of data or is it 0 bytes?

Comment: rmaddy I believe the issue is happening when `_previewData` is written to path or when `_previewData` is set with dataWithContentsOfFile. It has some data (~89 bytes), but it when I paste it in iMessage for example, it doesn't send and it is not viewable (when tapped on). `_previewData` does have data in it initially though (I can copy it and paste it without a problem)

Comment: First, you forgot to mention that you were attempting to use [this library](https://github.com/unixpickle/MP4Audio/). I quickly tested your code, and it would indeed seem to be a problem with that library. I would suggest finding a different tool for changing the album artwork of an audio file.